# Cannot use next() on iterable object created using *[Symbol.iterator]() generator javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

Ive tried Googling this and looking through similar questions but I seem to be missing something fundamental

```
let collection = {
    items: [],
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let item of this.items) {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}
collection.items.push(1);
collection.items.push(2);
console.log(collection.next());
```

This throws an error

```
console.log(collection.next());
                       ^

TypeError: collection.next is not a function
```

From my reading I should be able to use next() on the collection object because that would call the Symbol.iterator property?

Comment: No, `.next()` is on the object returned from the first call. Try using your object in a `for ... of` or `Array.from()` or something like that.

Comment: `for (let i of collection) console.log(i);` returns the two numbers I pushed into the items array property property. So that is working fine, it is just the next method that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `[Symbol.iterator]()` method to get an iterator object, and then call the `next()` method on the returned object:

```js
let collection = {
  items: [],
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let item of this.items) {
      yield item;
    }
  }
};

collection.items.push(1);
collection.items.push(2);

let iterator = collection[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
```

Keep in mind the array itself already implements the iterable protocol, which you in fact used in your `[Symbol.iterator]()` definition through the use of the `for...of` loop, so the `collection` object isn't really necessary here:

```js
let items = [];

items.push(1);
items.push(2);

let iterator = items[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
```

Comment: I understand that 'array' is already any iterable. I was trying to create a new collection object that has exotic properties that could be customised. This is probably rather arcane. However I think I get the idea that a new iterable object should probably not create a `next` method in a singleton style but should instead create an iterator each time, so that we can have more than one iterator running at the same time.

Comment: @lindsaymacvean yes. The only time the same object should implement both is if your iterator object references itself to be conveniently used as an iterable, e.g. `let iterator = { [Symbol.iterator]() { return this; }, next() { /* some non-trivial implementation */ } };`

Answer (score -1):

There are actually two different protocols

- 'Iterable' - which is what I implemented using the `*[Symbol.iterator]()` generator. This allows for...of loops etc.

and

- 'Iterator' - which means to define a next method on the object.

To quote from documentation:

> it is easy to create an object that satisfies both the iterator and iterable protocols (as shown in the example below).
> Doing so allows an iterator to be consumed by the various syntaxes expecting iterables. Thus, it is seldom useful to implement the Iterator Protocol without also implementing Iterable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

So I have rewritten my code thus:

```
let collection = {
    items: [],
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let item of this.items) {
            yield item;
        }
    },
    i: 0,
    next: function() {
        let done = (this.i >= this.items.length);
        let value = !done ? this.items[this.i++] : undefined
        return {
            done,
            value
        }
    }
}
collection.items.push(1);
collection.items.push(2);
for (let i of collection) console.log(i); // demonstrates the iterable protocol
console.log(collection.next()); // demonstrates the iterator protocol
console.log(collection.next());
console.log(collection.next());
```

A final note, this is not a private object and should be wrapped inside a class or immediately invoked function to avoid these properties being accessible to any other code etc.